# Cannot debug the code in PyCharm 2020.1 - Python 3.5 EOL bug

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.5

I am getting the following error whenever I try to debug any code. Running the code works fine though.
I have tried few suggestions from the forums, with no luck.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 39, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_comm import CMD_SET_BREAK, CMD_SET_NEXT_STATEMENT, CMD_STEP_INTO, CMD_STEP_OVER, \
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 96, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_bytecode_utils
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_bytecode_utils.py", line 105, in <module>
    _unpack_opargs = dis._unpack_opargs
AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3.5 has reached EOL](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3510/). As such, PyCharm 20.1 (and newer, most likely) apparently does not fully support it. See PyCharm issue [PY-41642](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41642).

**Edit: [Actually, it appears that PyCharm 20.1.1 included the fix for it, so actually try a newer version first](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+2020.1.1+Release+Notes)** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> the page for PY-41642).

You have 3 options (ordered from best to worst):

- Upgrade to a newer Python version
- Install an older version of PyCharm
- Use the workaround suggested at the above link by manually editing PyCharm files

Comment: Installed an older version of PyCharm, as upgrading to newer python version was not possible due to dependency projects involved that needed older version.